# Get parentNode tagName

Tags: javascript, styles, tagname

I'cant get parentNode.tagName from this code and put some style to `li` tag.

```
// path to catalog images
var img = $('.catalog ul li > img');
for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    var pic_real_width;
    // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img[i]).attr("src")).load(function () {
        pic_real_width = this.width;

        if (pic_real_width > 500) {
            // this part of code not work
            var imageParent = this.parenNode.tagName = 'li';
            imageParent.style.width = '50%';
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: But where in your code are you trying to read `parentNode.tagName` ??

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without the associated HTML ? I would suggest making a fiddle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `parenNode` instead of `parentNode`, and you seem to be assigning to that property, which is read-only.

```
    // ---------------------v             v---assignment won't work
var imageParent = this.parentNode.tagName = 'li';
```

---

If you just wanted the parent, there's no reason to mess with the `.tagName`.

```
var imageParent = this.parentNode;
imageParent.style.width = '50%';
```

---

Also, I don't see where you're appending the new `<img>` to the DOM. If it's not appended, it won't have a parent.

Maybe you meant to get the parent of the original image. To do that, each `load()` handler will need to close over the current `i` or `img`. You can use `.each()` to accomplish this.

```
$('.catalog ul li > img')
    .each(function(i, img) {
        var pic_real_width;

        $("<img/>").attr("src", $(img).attr("src")).load(function () {
            pic_real_width = this.width;

            if (pic_real_width > 500) {
                var imageParent = img.parentNode;
                imageParent.style.width = '50%';
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: @Constantyn: Yes, see my updated answer. You never appended the new `<img>` to the DOM, so it doesn't have a parent *(so it's `null`)*. I assume you actually want the parent of the original image. I added a solution to handle this.